# How To Insert Text From Input Field Into PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, post, input, sendgrid

I have a form with input fields that when submited sends an email out through a WebAPI from SendGrid.  Without writing out the whole come here are the important parts:


HTML:

```
<form action="sent.php" method="post">

<label>To:</label>

<input name="to" type="text" size="95" />

<label>Subject:</label>

<input name="subject" type="text" size="95" />

<label>Message:</label>

<textarea name="message" type="text" cols="71" rows="30"></textarea>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send"/>

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require 'SendGrid_loader.php';

print "I'm setting up variables here\n";
$user = 'XXXX';
$password = 'XXXX';
$to_email = array('XXXX@yahoo.com','XXXX@gmail.com','XXXXhotmail.com');


print "I'm creating a new SendGrid account\n";
$sendgrid = new SendGrid($user,$password);


$mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
$mail->setTos($to_email)
    ->setFrom('jacob@jacob.com')
    ->setSubject($_POST['subject'])
    ->setText($_POST['message'])
    ->setFromName('Jacob');

print "about to send email\n";
$result=$sendgrid->web->send($mail);

print_r($result);
```

What I am trying to do is allow someone to enter multiple email addresses in the "To:" input field seperate by a comma (i.e. To: "john@gmail.com, sue@gmail.com, gill@gmail.com") and have them entered into the array in the PHP file.  I am trying to do this without having to create more than one To: input field.

Any suggestions?

Thank You

!UPDATE:

The PHP explode() Function worked.  Here is my updated working code:


HTML:

```
<form action="sent.php" method="post">

<label>To:</label>

<input name="to" type="text" size="95" />

<label>Subject:</label>

<input name="subject" type="text" size="95" />

<label>Message:</label>

<textarea name="message" type="text" cols="71" rows="30"></textarea>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send"/>

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require 'SendGrid_loader.php';

print "I'm setting up variables here\n";
$user = 'XXXXXXX';
$password = 'XXXXXXX';
$str = $_POST['to'];
$to_email = explode(",", $str);


print "I'm creating a new SendGrid account\n";
$sendgrid = new SendGrid($user,$password);


$mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
$mail->setTos($to_email)
    ->setFrom('jacob@jacob.com')
    ->setSubject($_POST['subject'])
    ->setText($_POST['message'])
    ->setFromName('Jacob');

print "about to send email\n";
$result=$sendgrid->web->send($mail);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://php.net/explode 
You have a comma separated list you want to turn into an array? Use explode.